# Python encoded message with HMAC-SHA256

Tags: python, encode, hmac

I try to encoded message with HMAC-SHA256 in Python according to [instructions][1]

```
import hmac
import hashlib

nonce = 1234
customer_id = 123232
api_key = 2342342348273482374343434
API_SECRET = 892374928347928347283473

message = nonce + customer_id + api_key
signature = hmac.new(
    API_SECRET,
    msg=message,
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest().upper()
```

but I get this

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "gen.py", line 13, in
>
> digestmod=hashlib.sha256   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 136, in new
> return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/hmac.py", line 71, in **init**
> if len(key) > blocksize: TypeError: object of type 'long' has no len()

Does anyone have any idea why crashes?
[1]: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/#account-balance

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're using numbers where the api expects a string/bytes.

```
# python 2
import hmac
import hashlib

nonce = 1234
customer_id = 123232
api_key = 2342342348273482374343434
API_SECRET = 892374928347928347283473

message = '{} {} {}'.format(nonce, customer_id, api_key)
signature = hmac.new(
    str(API_SECRET),
    msg=message,
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest().upper()

print signature
```

Answer (score 51):

If you want to execute in python3 you should do the following:

```
#python 3
import hmac
import hashlib

nonce = 1
customer_id = 123456
API_SECRET = 'thekey'
api_key = 'thapikey'

message = '{} {} {}'.format(nonce, customer_id, api_key)

signature = hmac.new(
    bytes(API_SECRET, 'latin-1'), 
    msg=bytes(message, 'latin-1'), 
    digestmod=hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest().upper()
print(signature)
```

Comment: Why use latin-1?

Comment: `signature = hmac.new(bytes(API_SECRET , 'utf-8'), msg = bytes(message , 'utf-8'), digestmod = hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()`

Comment: @Ahmed Very commonly HMAC is used to sign HTTP requests.  The exact "message" it signs is often a composition of the HTTP headers and a hex-encoded hash of the message body. HTTP headers are almost exclusively ISO-8859-1 (latin 1) [see here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987).  So in 99% of cases where people want this example they will want to encode with latin 1.  Both sender and recipient need to know what encoding to expect.  If you want this for something other than HTTP latin 1 might not be correct.

Comment: It is probable that using a constant nonce makes no sense and may leave you open to attacks? Or not? Why is the nonce constant?

Comment: `signature = hmac.new(key=bytes(str(API_SECRET), 'utf-8'), msg=bytes(message, 'utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()` incase `API_SECRET` isn't a string

Comment: @bn_ln Why rely on some random string conversion for `API_SECRET`? Why not just ensure it is in the right format. I don't want to call `str(None)` or something like that.