# Generate SHA256 HMAC signature in Python

Tags: python, hmac

I'm trying to generate a SHA256 HMAC signature for a FTX websocket. I am using the params fromt he official example https://docs.ftx.com/#private-channels.

It should generate d10b5a67a1a941ae9463a60b285ae845cdeac1b11edc7da9977bef0228b96de9

but I am getting ad38fa3566de972abb736bc0db2f7cd39daa48b14421e168422303bf2f03c6de

here is what I tried:

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

time = '1557246346499'
secret = 'Y2QTHI23f23f23jfjas23f23To0RfUwX3H42fvN-'


digest = hmac.new(bytes(time, 'UTF-8'),
                bytes(secret, 'UTF-8'), hashlib.sha256)
signature = digest.hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes: first, `hmac.new()` takes the arguments in the reverse order: `hmac.new(secret, msg, digestmod)`, and second, the message should be `<time>websocket_login`:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

time = '1557246346499'
secret = 'Y2QTHI23f23f23jfjas23f23To0RfUwX3H42fvN-'


digest = hmac.new(
    secret.encode(), 
    f'{time}websocket_login'.encode(),
    hashlib.sha256
)
signature = digest.hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with these things, but your code differs from the one I found in [Python encoded message with HMAC-SHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38133665/python-encoded-message-with-hmac-sha256), message and key seem to be swapped.
That would be a duplicate only, however another thing is that the documentation you link says

> `sign`: SHA256 HMAC of the following string, using your API secret: `<time>websocket_login`

So it's not `1557246346499`, but `1557246346499websocket_login` what you need.

Put together:

```
import hmac
import hashlib

time = '1557246346499websocket_login'
secret = 'Y2QTHI23f23f23jfjas23f23To0RfUwX3H42fvN-'


signature = hmac.new(bytes(secret , 'latin-1'), msg = bytes(time , 'latin-1'), digestmod = hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print(signature)
```

Generates the expected output.